# iOS adding an animation with Pan Gesture Recognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to make an animation within a pan gesture recognizer. However, when the recognizer gets to my desired location on the screen, the UIStateGestureRecognizerStateEnded gets called, and my animation does not get fired properly. This is how I am going about doing that. How can I make it so that my animation is smooth and doesn't disrupt the gesture recognizer's state.

```
-(IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
    recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x, recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
    self.lineView1.center = CGPointMake(self.lineView1.center.x, recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y - 337.5f);
    self.lineView2.center = CGPointMake(self.lineView2.center.x, recognizer.view.center.y +translation.y + 337.5f);
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];

    //THIS CODE IS NOT ALLOWING THE ANIMATION TO RUN SMOOTHLY? AND ENDS THE GESTURE'S STATE. 
    if ((recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y)>300 && (recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y)<345) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:3.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
            self.joinHorzConst.constant= 60;
            self.joinLabel.alpha = 1;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            //completion
        }];
    }



    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.35 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                         animations:^{
                             recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x, 121.5f);
                             self.lineView1.center = CGPointMake(281, -216);
                             self.lineView2.center = CGPointMake(281, 459);
                         } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                             [UIView animateWithDuration:.2 animations:^{
                                 recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x, 147.5f);
                                 self.lineView1.center = CGPointMake(281, -189);
                                 self.lineView2.center = CGPointMake(281, 486);                             } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                     [UIView animateWithDuration:.1 animations:^{
                                         recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x, 141.5f);
                                         self.lineView1.center = CGPointMake(281, -196);
                                         self.lineView2.center = CGPointMake(281, 479);

                                     }];
                                 }];

                         }];
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Exactly how I want my animation to work:

user drags a recognizer up and down a y axis, like a slider. When the slider button reaches within certain y axises (300 - 345), I want there to be an animation on one of my labels that just pushes it to the left a bit and turns the alpha up.

How it is working right now:

Right now, the slider works fine, UNTILL i reach the y axis between 300-345, at that point my gestureReconizerStatedidEnd gets called and the slider returns to its original position with the desired animation. I dont want this to happen. I want the slider to keep moving freely, but the label animation to happen just as the slider is within those 300-345 dimensions.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your trying to do,but can't you just set the location continuously when it's state is `Chaged`?

Comment: I edited my question to have a clearer explanation of how I want my animation to work. @Linuxios

Answer (score 0):

The way I was setting the labels x value with constraints seemed to be disrupting the gesture? Not sure. But here is how it is working now.

```
  if ((recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y)>300 && (recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y)<345) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
            [self.joinLabel setCenter:CGPointMake(183, 324)];
            self.joinLabel.alpha = 1;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            //completion
        }];
    }
```